# How to replace Home Page HTML Area components with Visualforce components in a Managed Package for subscribers?

Tags: managed-package, home-page-component

As we all know with Summer 15, salesforce will be removing supportf or HTMl Area home page components.

So my concern is how can we replace Home Page HTML Area components with Visualforce components in a Managed Package for subscribers?

I've packaged couple of HTML Area components in my app, and it is a managed package and has been installed in customer orgs. I have created new Home Page Components as Visualforce components but I'm not known of a way on how to make them replace existing subscribers.

Can anyone suggest how we can replace the old components with the new ones?